# How to Exclude NaNs from Pandas Rolling, but not return NaN if there is one in the DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Currently I have the DataFrame seen below and I want to do a rolling average over the last 10 occurrences that have actual values, but to skip the NaNs
[Example DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JtpH.png)

The issues is that if I run `df['AST_Hit'].rolling(10).mean(skipna=True).shift(1)` I get this DataFrame below which is not what I am looking for
[Example Output DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cX3D.png)

I've tried using window and min_period but that does not give me what I want as I don't want the average over anything greater than 10.

Ideally I would like the DataFrame to be able to discard a NaN, but still look to see if there are 10 values in that selection. From what I am describing I think I need some sort of max period where it is equal to 10 as well as the min period equal to 10, but I could not find anything on Pandas documentation for rolling on setting up a max period.

Maybe it would also be best if I just dropped any NaN rows. My DataFrame is much bigger than what is seen, so it isn't just those 3 rows that contain a NaN, but it may be the best course of action

Any help or tips is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a sample DataFrame with non-numeric columns
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', periods=100),
    'AST_Hit': np.random.randint(0, 10, size=100),
    'Other_Column': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'] * 10
})
df.iloc[3:6, 1] = np.nan
df.iloc[7, 0] = np.nan
df.iloc[10:15, 2] = np.nan
df.iloc[20:25, 1] = np.nan
df.iloc[30:40, 2] = np.nan

# compute rolling average over the last 10 non-null values
rolling_mask = df['AST_Hit'].notnull().rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).sum().eq(10)
result = df['AST_Hit'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x[rolling_mask]))

print(result)
```

which gives

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
     ... 
95    5.6
96    5.1
97    4.7
98    4.2
99    3.9
Name: AST_Hit, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```